# C - Trouble creating a matrix of char strings

Tags: c

UPDATE: Figured it out... updated code at the bottom of bugged code does as it should.
Thanks guys

I'm trying to read lines from an input.txt file into three matrices, one for first names, one for last names, one for grades.

The grade matrix is fine, I can't figure out the names matrices.

When run I get output:

```
Row 1, column 1 of grades: 1.30
Row 1, column 1 of first: P
Row 1, column 1 of last: V
```

Which is incorrect for the character arrays.

I'm thinking the problem is how the arrays first and last are initialized.
First instance of this here:

```
//Store first token in first[][]
if(counter == 1){
first[i][j] = token;
}
```

Is this the proper way to store a string called token into the index [0][0] of the array first[][]?

What is the proper way to initialize a matrix of character strings?
I need the first row to contain the first name,
second row to contain the second name,
etc.

I have a hard time visualizing an actual matrix vs how they're stored in RAM (I understand the name of an array is a pointer to the first index of an array, but when it gets to 2d arrays, I can't visualize the pointers how they're structured in RAM)

input.txt file:

```
Alice Wonderland 1.3 2 3 4 5.5
Bob Marley 7 8 9.8 10 11.5
Charley Manson 12 13.5 14 15 16
```

Code:

```
/* Input: input file name, as char array;
          matrix of names, and matrix of grades
   Functionality: opens the file, extracts names into matrix of names,
                  extracts grades into the matrix of grades;
   Output: 0 if everything went well, -1 otherwise
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXNUMSTUDENT 100
#define MAXNUMGRADES 100

//#define DEBUG1
#define DEBUG2

char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][1]; //One first name per row (one column)
char last[MAXNUMSTUDENT][1];  //One last name per row (one column)
float grades[MAXNUMGRADES][MAXNUMGRADES];
float grade;




int counter = 1; //Counts the token number (First two tokens = names, rest = grades)
int i = 0; //Row index
int j = 0; //Column index for first[][], last[][]
int n = 0; //Row index for grades[][]
int m = 0; //Column index for grades[][]

int main(void)
{
    //Initialize all arrays to 0

    // First[i][j]
    for(i=0; i<MAXNUMSTUDENT; i++){
        first[i][j] = "0";
        for(j=0; j<=1; j++){
            first[i][j] = "0";
        }
    }

    // Last[i][j]
    for(i=0; i<MAXNUMSTUDENT; i++){
        last[i][j] = "0";
        for(j=0; j<=1; j++){
            last[i][j] = "0";
        }        

    }

    // grades[n][m]
    for(n=0; n<MAXNUMGRADES; n++){
        grades[n][m] = 0;
        for(m=0; m<MAXNUMGRADES; m++){
            grades[n][m] = 0;
        }
    }

    //Reset indexes
    i=0;
    j=0;
    n=0;
    m=0;

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("gradebook.txt", "r");  //Name of input file goes here
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;

    //Loops through each line of gradebook (1 loop = 1 line)
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

        /****   AT THIS POINT YOU HAVE A STRING CALLED line *****/


        char delim[] = " ";   //delimiters are space comma and hyphen

        char* token;

        //For loop tokenizes string, runs until there are no more tokens
        for (token = strtok(line, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim))
        {   
            #ifdef DEBUG1
            printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
            printf("%s\n", line);
            printf("token=%s counter=%d i=%d j=%d n=%d m=%d\n\n", token, counter, i, j, n, m);
            #endif

            //Store first token in first[][]
            if(counter == 1){
                first[i][j] = token;
            }

            //Store second token in last[][]
            if(counter == 2){
                last[i][j] = token;

                //Increment row of first[][] and last[][] (for next line)
                i++;
            }

            //Store the rest of tokens in grades[][]
            if(counter > 2){
                grade = atof(token);
                grades[n][m] = grade;

                //Increment column of grades[][]
                m++;
            }

        //Counter for token number
        counter++;
        }

        //Increment row of grades[][]
        n++;

        //Reset counter
        counter = 1;

        //Reset column index of grades[][]
        m = 0;
    }


    //Test arrays
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of grades: %.2f\n", grades[0][0]);
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of first: %c\n", first[0][0]);
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of last: %c\n", last[0][0]);

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

UPDATED CODE :

```
/*  File    : extractgrades.c          *
*   team    : SnS                   *
*   Date    : 11-20-16           */

/* Input: input file name, as char array;
          matrix of names, and matrix of grades
   Functionality: opens the file, extracts names into matrix of names,
                  extracts grades into the matrix of grades;
   Output: 0 if everything went well, -1 otherwise
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXNUMSTUDENT 100
#define MAXNUMGRADES 100

//Comment out to turn off debugging
#define DEBUG1
#define DEBUG2

char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][MAXNUMSTUDENT]; 
char last[MAXNUMSTUDENT][MAXNUMSTUDENT];  
float grades[MAXNUMGRADES][MAXNUMGRADES];

int numberofscores; //Number of scores
int numberofstudents;
int maxnumberofscores;

int main(void)
{
    char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][MAXNUMSTUDENT] = {{0}}; 
    char last[MAXNUMSTUDENT][MAXNUMSTUDENT] = {{0}}; 
    float grades[MAXNUMGRADES][MAXNUMGRADES] = {{0}};
    float grade;

    int i; //Row index
    int j; //Column index for first[][], last[][]
    int n; //Row index for grades[][]
    int m; //Column index for grades[][]
    int counter; //Counts the token number (First two tokens = names, rest = grades)

    //Initialize indexes
    counter=1;
    numberofscores=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    n=0;
    m=0;

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("gradebook.txt", "r");  //Name of input file goes here
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;

    //Loops through each line of gradebook (1 loop = 1 line)
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

        char delim[] = " ";   //delimiters are space comma and hyphen
        char * token;

        //For loop tokenizes string, runs until there are no more tokens
        for (token = strtok(line, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim))
        {   
            #ifdef DEBUG1
                printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
                printf("%s\n", line);
                printf("token=%s counter=%d i=%d j=%d n=%d m=%d\n\n", token, counter, i, j, n, m);
            #endif

            //Store first token in first[][]
            if(counter == 1){
               strcpy(first[i], token);
            }

            //Store second token in last[][]
            if(counter == 2){
                strcpy(last[i], token);
                //Increment row of first[][] and last[][] (for next line)
                i++;
            }

            //Store the rest of tokens in grades[][]
            if(counter > 2){
                grade = atof(token);
                grades[n][m] = grade;

                //Increment column of grades[][]
                m++;
            }

        //Counter for token number
        counter++;
        }

        //Save pseudo max number of scores
        maxnumberofscores = counter;
        if(counter >= maxnumberofscores){
            maxnumberofscores = counter;
        }
        printf("maxnumberofscores: %d\n", maxnumberofscores);

        //Increment row of grades[][]
        n++;

        //Reset column index of grades[][]
        m = 0;

        //Reset counter
        counter = 1;
    }

    //Get actual max number of scores
    numberofscores = maxnumberofscores - 3;

    //Get number of students
    numberofstudents = i;


  //Debug sandwich to test everything
  #ifdef DEBUG2
    //Test arrays
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of grades: %.2f\n", grades[0][0]);
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of first: %c\n", first[0][0]);
    printf("Row 1, column 1 of last: %c\n", last[0][0]);

    //Print all arrays
    i=0;
    j=0;
    n=0;
    m=0;

    //Print grades[n][m]
    for(n=0; n<numberofstudents; n++){
        printf("\n");
        for(m=0; m<numberofscores; m++){
            printf("grades[%d][%d]: %.2f\n", n, m, grades[n][m]);
        }
    }

    //Print first[i][j]
    for(i=0; i<numberofstudents; i++){
        printf("first[%d]: %s\n", i, first[i]);
    }

    //Print last[i][j]
    for(i=0; i<numberofstudents; i++){
        printf("last[%d]: %s\n", i, last[i]);
    }

    //Print number of scores, number of students
    printf("Max number of scores = %d\n", numberofscores);
    printf("Number of students: %d\n", numberofstudents);    
  #endif


    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
first[i][j] = "0";
```

`first[i][j]` is a `char` (not a string), change to

```
first[i][j] = '0';
```

> Is this the proper way to store a string called token into the index
>   [0][0] of the array first[][]?

```
first[i][j] = token;
```

No, first, you can not assign to an array using `=`, you need to use some function like `strcpy` or better yet a safer version like `strlcpy` or `snprintf`.

Second, your array only haves space for one character:

```
char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][1];
```

You need more room:

```
char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][100];
```

Also, you are freeing `line` at the end, but you need to call `free` each time you call `getline` in order to avoid memory leaks:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    ...
    free(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of arrays is not correct

```
char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][1]
```

only allocates MAXNUMSTUDENT of 1 char.

For C the above is just a block of memory with size MAXNUMSTUDENT characters regardless of the number of dimensions you give it. The dimensions are instead used when you de-reference the memory block to calculate the offset in the memory block.

What you need is something like

```
char first[MAXNUMSTUDENT][MAX_LENGTH_NAME];
```

Where MAX_LENGTH_NAME is the number of characters that a first name can have plus one char for the ending \0. Same goes for the other arrays.

However this looks like a case where dynamic memory allocation would be better.

So instead of allocating the array of chars allocate an array of pointers to strings.

```
char* first[MAXNUMSTUDENT]
```

then when you strtok the line allocate and copy the strings

```
first[i] = strdup(token); // same as malloc/strcpy
```

I think also it would be better if you put all the student information into a struct instead.

```
struct student
{
  char* first;
  char* last;
  char* grades; 
};

...

struct student students[MAXNUMSTUDENT];

..

students[i].first = strdup(token);
```

Of course you also make the array dynamic instead of declaring it with a fixed size which could have an initial size of MAXNUMSTUDENT

```
struct student** students;
students = malloc(sizeof(struct student*) * MAXNUMSTUDENT);
```

and can later be changed with `realloc()`

Comment: 'only allocates MAXNUMSTUDENT of 1 char "strings"' - no need for the quotes, they're simply not strings, but single `char` objects.